# How to Change Mysql Insert Join Query to Codeigniter Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_person  (person_name,person_gender,person_address,
                        person_placeofbirth,person_dateofbirth,
                        person_religion,person_phonenumber,person_email,
                        person_image,person_status) 
VALUES ('Fadilis', 'Male','Jl.kaliurang km 7',
        'Solo','1991-3-24',
        'islam','08996787262','fadil@gmail.com',
        'fadil.jpg','aktif');

INSERT INTO tbl_user (username, password, person_id,role_id) 
VALUES ('Fadil', 'polisi',(select person_id FROM tbl_person 
         where person_name = 'Fadilis'), (select role_id from ref_role 
         where role_name = 'admin'));

SELECT u.username, u.password, p.person_name , p.person_gender, 
        p.person_address, p.person_placeofbirth, p.person_dateofbirth, 
        p.person_religion, p.person_phonenumber,
        p.person_email, p.person_status, r.role_name
from tbl_user u 
    inner join tbl_person p on u.person_id = p.person_id 
    inner join ref_role r on u.role_id = r.role_id
```

Can you tell me way to change this query to codeigniter active record?

Comment: That is 3 queries, I think

Comment: can you give me example to execute that 3 query into 1 function in model, coz, i'm newbie in codeigniter

Comment: ...then you'd better take a look at CodeIgniter Query Builder documentation: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=active%20record#query-builder-class

Comment: thanks for ur advice @MarcM

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
$data = array(
   'person_name' => 'Fadilis' ,
   'person_gender' => 'Male' ,
   'person_address' => 'Jl.kaliurang km 7',
   'person_placeofbirth' => 'Solo',
   'person_dateofbirth' => '1991-3-24',
   'person_religion' => 'islam',
   'person_phonenumber' => '08996787262',
   'person_email' => 'fadil@gmail.com',
   'person_image' => 'fadil.jpg',
   'person_status' => 'aktif',
);
$this->db->insert('tbl_person', $data);
```

Second:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_user (username, password, person_id,role_id) 
VALUES ('Fadil', 'polisi',(select person_id FROM tbl_person 
         where person_name = 'Fadilis'), (select role_id from ref_role 
         where role_name = 'admin'));

$select = $this->db->select('select person_id')->from('tbl_person')->where('person_name', 'Fadilis');
$select2 = $this->db->select('select role_id')->from('ref_role')->where('role_name', 'admin');

$data = array(
  'username' => 'Fadil' ,
  'password' => 'polisi' ,
  'person_id' => $select->result_array(),
  'role_id' => $select2->result_array()
);         
$this->db->insert('tbl_user', $data);
```

With this examples you can do the third, this is the join sintaxis:

```
$this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('blogs');
  $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');

  $query = $this->db->get();
```

You should read documentation documentation:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Comment: In the second i wrote your original query,  before mine. I hope you can vote for me.

Comment: i wanna to vote you, but it seem my rep not meet requarements. maybe next time